# Google lists this gif several thousand times as not having a license, is it safe to post on my company's Twitter account?

Tags: images, licenses

I found a GIF of a guy skeet shooting listed on several sites and I've posted it in my Twitter account below:

https://twitter.com/leeand00/status/488894537599680515

I looked up the image on Google Images and it's listed several thousand times as having no license associated with it.  When I check the other license types it isn't listed there at all.

Would I be posting this to my non-profits' account at our own risk?  Or does the fact that there is no license listed on Google make the image free game?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was taken from a video, rather than created for a gif.

Specifically, this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5uHt4AwYb4

I personally wouldn't worry about copyright issues in this case - the fact the video has been there since 2007 suggests that the owner isn't that bothered, even though he is more likely to make money from selling videos than gifs.

It's also quite low-res.  If the owner was selling it, then I'm sure it would be higher quality.

I wouldn't go as far as saying "free game", but there are so many "content sharing" sites who actually make money from work they don't own, that I can't see anyone caring about a non-profit site using it.  Most websites have some content which is as legally dubious (**every** image on giphy, for example).

If you are really worried, just embed it direct from giphy and let them worry about take-down requests.

Crediting a source with a link whenever possible is seen as good etiquette.

Comment: So would this be considered...fair use?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but my understanding is that "fair use" requires some sort of change or comment on the original.  However, a 3 second silent loop of a video is so trivial that I think it is more a matter that no one would care.  Sites like Buzzfeed could not exist if they did.